# How can I change the date format of a string containing dates, in Matlab?

Tags: string, matlab, date, regexp-replace

Is there any way to change the date format in Matlab without first converting to a number?

Here is a pseducode example of what I mean:

```
timeString = '23/04/2016';
newFormat1 = 'yy-mm-dd';
myPseudoFun(timeString, newFormat1)

ans =

16-04-23


newFormat2 = 'dd mmm yyyy';
myPseudoFun(timeString, newFormat2)

ans =

23 Apr 2016
```

All help is much appreciated!

Comment: What's the problem with `datestr(datenum(timeString, oldFormat), newFormat)`? That's pretty much what any implementation of `myPseudoFun` would be doing...

Comment: I need to do this for, up to, 20 million elements

Answer (score 1):

Use the `datetime` datatype:
(Note the use of capital M's for month.  Lower case m is for minutes.)

```
>> timeString = datetime('23/04/2016','InputFormat','dd/MM/yyyy')
timeString = 
   23-Apr-2016
>> timeString.Format = 'yy-MM-dd'
timeString = 
   16-04-23
>> timeString.Format = 'dd MMM yyyy'
timeString = 
   23 Apr 2016
```

Comment: Worth noting that this data type was introduced in R2014b

Comment: Thanks @Phil Goddard. Unfortunately, this is too time consuming =/